# Warning: No matches found for: kernel-devel

Tags: linux-kernel, yum

When I'm trying to install `kernel-devel` from yum source, I got the error:

```
$ sudo yum search kernel-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.riken.jp
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
 * extras: ftp.riken.jp
 * updates: ftp.riken.jp
Warning: No matches found for: kernel-devel
No Matches found

[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 ~]$ uname -r
2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 ~]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

But in my another CentOS 6.4 machine, `kernel-devel`(2.6.32-358.) can be found and installed normally. So I just doubt that bad things have been done to my os system, or the kernel-devel version 2.4.32-431 do not exist truly.

This problem occurs in my vagrant vm.

Answer (score 0):

you should disable the `versionlock` plugin.

edit `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/versionlock.conf` set `enabled = 0`, and retry `yum install kernel-devel`

**NOTICE**

if you upgrade the kernel to a newer version, when you reload vagrant, it would cause an error

> Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
>   the "vboxsf" file system is not available

you can fix it by running `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup`